# Java- How to get multiple IDs in a Spring Boot REST Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a Rest Endpoint
`http://localhost:8080/api/invoice`
I want to create another endpoint where I can get multiple ids like
`http://localhost:8080/api/invoice?id[in]=1,2,3`

How can I achieve it in Spring Boot?

Comment: with a normal request `http://localhost:8080/api/invoice?id=1&id=2&id=3` it would be easy. why do you use  `?id[in]=1,2,3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a standard request like `http://localhost:8080/messages?id=1&id=2&id=3` it is easy.

You can get (multiple) ids via `@RequestParam(value = "id") List<Integer> ids`

*example:*

```java
@RestController
class DemoController{
    Map<Integer,String> messages = Map.of(1,"Hello 1", 2 , "Hello 2", 3, "Hello 3" , 4, "Hello 4", 5, "Hello 5" );

    @GetMapping("/messages") // http://localhost:8080/api/invoice?id=1&id=2&id=3
    List<String> messages(@RequestParam(value = "id") List<Integer> ids){
        // do the lookup by ids...
        return messages.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter( e -> ids.contains(e.getKey()))
                    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

---

Technically you could handle a RequestParam like `id[in]`, but I would **not** recommend it.

- First of all, a `[` or `]`-char are not allowed in a URL by default
- You need to do extra work to retrieve the actual ids

*application.properties* : make sure tomcat allows `[` + `]`

```
server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars=[,]
```

*handle the request in your controller*

```
 @GetMapping("/messages") // => http://localhost:8080/messages?id[in]=1,2,3
 List<String> messages(@RequestParam(value = "id[in]") String ids) {
  // get the actual ids from the string     
  final List<Integer> idList = 
        Arrays.stream(ids.split(","))
              .map(id -> Integer.parseInt(id))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
     // do your lookup by ids...
     return messages.entrySet().stream()
                .filter( e -> idList.contains(e.getKey()))
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for my bad question. Thank you very much, Dirk.

Comment: @Phil this DOES work, demo here: [multiple-ids-in-a-spring-boot-rest-controller](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/multiple-ids-in-a-spring-boot-rest-controller)

Comment: @DirkDeyne sorry, you are right, my Error was from Spring Data, not MVC